# How to programmatically add a Vertical or Horizontal StackView to a view

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, monodevelop

I'm able to add a Vertical and Horizontal StackView programmatically to my main view but the view is not performing any stacking type layout.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// create vertical stack
var viewSize = new CGSize(200, 150);
var viewLocation = new CGPoint(0, 0);

var viewRectangle = new CGRect(viewLocation, viewSize);
var frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 20);

var stackView = new NSStackView(viewRectangle);

var button1 = new NSButton(frame) {
    Title = "Button 1"
};

var frame2 = new CGRect(0, 10, 200, 20);
var button2 = new NSButton(frame2) {
    Title = "Button 2"
};

// show background to help see size and position
stackView.WantsLayer = true;
stackView.Layer.BackgroundColor = new CGColor(150, 0, 150, 1);

stackView.Orientation = NSUserInterfaceLayoutOrientation.Vertical;
stackView.Alignment = NSLayoutAttribute.Top;
stackView.Distribution = NSStackViewDistribution.Fill;
stackView.Spacing = 10;

stackView.AddSubview(button1);
stackView.AddSubview(button2);
stackView.NeedsLayout = true;

frame1.AddSubview(stackView);
```

Screenshot below.

The top view is a manually created Vertical Stack in Interface Builder. The bottom is the programmatic one created from the code above:

[image]

**Update:**

I found some example code in the Xamarin iOS documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uistackview

There are some properties I can't find but some of it is working.

The main enabling difference is that you need to use the addArrangedSubViews() method instead of addSubviews() method.

```
stackView.AddArrangedSubview(button);
```

Visual Studio for Mac using Xamarin and C#

Comment: @gigawatts So you resolved your problem by self?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT i think so. Some properties are still missing but i might be able to get by. In iOS Stack have a margin or edge property. I can't find the same thing.